# pandas resample doesn't work with numpy 1.7

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

This code worked on my other computer with NumPy 1.6:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

datapath='C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/samoa/WATERSHED_ANALYSIS/FAGAALU/MasterDataFiles/FP-Master.csv'#):

col_names = ['Date', 'Time', 'TempOut', 'HiTemp', 'LowTemp', 'OutHum', 'DewPt', 'WindSpeed', 'WindDir', 'WindRun', 'HiSpeed', 'HiDir', 'WindChill', 'HeatIndex', 'THWIndex', 'Bar', 'Rain', 'RainRate', 'HeatD-D', 'CoolD-D', 'InTemp', 'InHum', 'InDew', 'InHeat', 'InEMC', 'InAirDensity', 'WindSamp', 'WindTx', 'ISSRecept', 'Arc.Int.']

Wx= pd.read_csv(datapath,skiprows=1,header=0,names=col_names,parse_dates=[['Date','Time']],index_col=['Date_Time'],na_values=['---'])
Wx.index = Wx.index.astype('datetime64')
Wx = Wx.resample('15Min',fill_method='pad',limit=2) ## fill the 30min intervals to 15minute
```

The column `'Date_Time'` is a combination of the csv file columns `'Date'` and `'Time'` and is formatted `"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"`

On a new computer with NumPy 1.7 I get this error:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 198, in astype
    return Index(self.values.astype(dtype), name=self.name,
ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic units
```

I've tried using `Wx.index = pd.to_datetime(Wx.index)`, but it fails to convert the index to a `DatetimeIndex`.

I've also tried using

```
Wx.index = Wx['Date_Time'].convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')
```

It converts the index to `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex`, but then

```
Wx.resample('15Min',,fill_method='pad',limit=2)
```

gives this error:

```
  File "tslib.pyx", line 1978, in pandas.tslib.normalize_date (pandas\tslib.c:30569)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Does anyone know why this won't work? I've tried using `.asfreq('15Min')` and then `.fillna('pad')`, but it's klunky and will require a lot of recoding for other modules.

Comment: astype is not necessary if your index parsed correctly (and the ``datetime64``) won't work anyhow, pls post Wx.index (immediately after being read from the csv), and a sample of your frame

Comment: also post: Wx.info() and your pandas version

Comment: Here is the Wx.index immediately after read_csv:    >>> Wx.index
Index([1/7/2012 10:30 AM, 1/7/2012 11:00 AM, 1/7/2012 11:30 AM, ..., 5/4/2013 10:00 AM, 5/4/2013 10:15 AM, 5/4/2013 10:30 AM], dtype=object)

Comment: >>> Wx.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 17396 entries, 1/7/2012 10:30 AM to 5/4/2013 10:30 AM
Data columns (total 28 columns):
TempOut         8471  non-null values
HiTemp          8470  non-null values
LowTemp         8470  non-null values
OutHum          8469  non-null values
DewPt           8469  non-null values
...
dtypes: float64(25), object(3)>>>

Comment: pandas version 0.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Something funny is going on when you parse the date columns. I would need to look at your file (post a link, or a part of in your question). Your parsing looks fine.In any event, `pd.to_datetime` will take what you posted and turn it into a `DatetimeIndex`, which is what you need for resample.

Try also

```
Wx.index = pd.todatetime(Wx.index.tolist())
```

Your index should be something like

```
In [26]: df.index
Out[26]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-07 10:30:00, ..., 2013-05-04 10:30:00]
Length: 6, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Here's the example

```
In [15]: index = pd.to_datetime('1/7/2012 10:30 AM, 1/7/2012 11:00 AM, 1/7/2012 11:30 AM, 5/4/2013 10:00 AM, 5/4/2013 10:15 AM, 5/4/2013 10:30 AM'.split(', '))

In [16]: df = DataFrame(randn(6,2),index=index)

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                            0         1
2012-01-07 10:30:00  0.523777 -0.093911
2012-01-07 11:00:00  0.954344  0.830551
2012-01-07 11:30:00 -0.004064 -1.831855
2013-05-04 10:00:00 -1.082163  1.426966
2013-05-04 10:15:00 -1.025252 -0.169916
2013-05-04 10:30:00  1.717222 -0.988228

In [18]: df.resample('15Min',fill_method='pad',limit=2).head(10)
Out[18]: 
                            0         1
2012-01-07 10:30:00  0.523777 -0.093911
2012-01-07 10:45:00  0.523777 -0.093911
2012-01-07 11:00:00  0.954344  0.830551
2012-01-07 11:15:00  0.954344  0.830551
2012-01-07 11:30:00 -0.004064 -1.831855
2012-01-07 11:45:00 -0.004064 -1.831855
2012-01-07 12:00:00 -0.004064 -1.831855
2012-01-07 12:15:00       NaN       NaN
2012-01-07 12:30:00       NaN       NaN
2012-01-07 12:45:00       NaN       NaN

In [19]: np.__version__
Out[19]: '1.7.1'
```

Here's an example file I parsed (just like you did)

```
In [32]: pd.read_csv('foo.csv',index_col=['Date_Time'],parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
Out[32]: 
                            0         1
Date_Time                              
2012-01-07 10:30:00  0.523777 -0.093911
2012-01-07 11:00:00  0.954344  0.830551
2012-01-07 11:30:00 -0.004064 -1.831855
2013-05-04 10:00:00 -1.082163  1.426966
2013-05-04 10:15:00 -1.025252 -0.169916
2013-05-04 10:30:00  1.717222 -0.988228

In [33]: !cat 'foo.csv'
Date,Time,0,1
2012-01-07,10:30:00 AM,0.5237774067993367,-0.0939112810613334
2012-01-07,11:00:00 AM,0.9543438182818779,0.8305511332193324
2012-01-07,11:30:00 AM,-0.004064420703945425,-1.8318551051738328
2013-05-04,10:00:00 AM,-1.082162936479846,1.4269663822610816
2013-05-04,10:15:00 AM,-1.0252522955053849,-0.16991623915937284
2013-05-04,10:30:00 AM,1.7172224344229594,-0.9882282095859544
```

Maybe somethings not aligned in your file, or you have some weird characters embeded in the Date/Time field?

Comment: Jeff, I think the above answer would work, but your first comment clued me in to the error in the date parsing in pd.read_csv. The .csv file had a blank line which caused an error in the date_parser. I wrote a custom date_parser to pass to read_csv and it works fine now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Here is what I used to fix it, in addition to fixing the file like you suggested! my_parser= lambda x,y: dt.datetime.strptime(x+y,"%m/%d/%Y%I:%M %p")
    Wx= pd.read_csv(datapath,skiprows=1,header=0,names=col_names,parse_dates=[['Date','Time']],index_col=['Date_Time'],date_parser=my_parser,na_values=['---'])

Comment: that looks right, FYI there is an option ``skiprows`` that takes a collection of rows to skip (e.g. blank lines ifyou want)

Comment: @AlexMessina If this answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so your question is marked as _solved_. Also, this gives both the poster of the answer and yourself some reputation points!